# PHP codes are commented on docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to up an website with php and apache httpd server with docker containers.

This is the folder structure of my project.

```
/ H:\test_projects\p1 /
├── public-html
│     └── proj1
│           └──index.php
└── docker-compose.yml
```

This is my **docker-compose.yml** file,

```
version: '3'

services:

  web:
      image: httpd
      ports:
          - '9090:80'
      volumes:
          - H:\test_projects\p1\public-html:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/
      depends_on:
          - php
          - mysql

  mysql:
    image: mysql

  php:
      image: php
```

This is **index.php** file of my project.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>My First Heading</h1>
        <p><?php echo 'mycode'; ?></p>
        <p>My first paragraph.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

But when I do docker compose up and go to http://localhost:9090/proj1/index.php I can see **PHP codes are not running and commented out in the browser**. Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: When you say `commented out in the browser` do you mean the PHP code is displayed as text?

Comment: as <!--?php echo 'mycode'; ?--> in inspect element and as <?php echo 'mycode'; ?> in page source. Think we need to connect PHP and HTTPD but not sure how :P

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue which is derived from the fact that the php container is not visible to the httpd container. The specific httpd container does not have php installed.

You can either replace both respective images with a joint image from the hub, like php:7.4-apache, or link the two containers through FPM. I coupled the containers using the following guide which worked in my case:

https://www.cloudreach.com/en/technical-blog/containerize-this-how-to-use-php-apache-mysql-within-docker-containers/